# Framework error in some transactions and different users AX 2012

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

In **Dynamics AX 2012 R2** randomly in different modules of the system a **.NET Framework** error arises. **AX** aborts the transaction and errors remain because the transaction does not complete.

This happens with different users and not always in the same processes.

Error:

[image]

> Uncontrolled exception in the application. If you click Continue the
> application will ignore this error and try to continue. If you click
> on Sair the application will be closed immediately.
>
> An external component produced an exception.

The environment is made up of a server for databases, another for AOS and another with access for clients.

Any advice?

Comment: Could you [edit] the question to share the error message in English or at least as text so we can use a translation service? Did you do a complete stop AOS, delete XppIL folder, compile, CIL compile, data dictionary sync cycle to ensure a clean system? Did you reset usage data?

Comment: Yes except delete XppIL folder.I will try again.

Comment: If you search for ".net exception sehexception ax 2012", you get several results for similar errors. Seems to be a generic issue that can be caused by different things. You will probably have to do some trial&error approach to get to a solution.

Comment: I'm going to say this isn't "random" and has a specific cause. It's an `SEH` exception. AOS is probably out of memory, some sort of hardware fault, in need of a hotfix, or it's failing whenever a `.NET` callout gets involved, such as workflow, which is setup around random modules. Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.sehexception?view=netcore-3.1

Does any of this sound like it could be close? We could narrow it down with more info. Is it truly totally random or is it whenever a similar process happens? Or do you have any 3rd party addons?

Comment: Is your environment virtualized or all on physical hardware? If it's directly on physical hardware...I'd keep that door open, that it could be equipment.